# Angular ui date picker short date format, incorrect past date/year after selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

UI date picker is showing incorrect date when, short date is selected from the format and any date in previous years like 1921 is selected, the date selected will be shown as in year 2021, ideally it should be shown as 1921.

Below is the official implementation, where it can be checked.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup

Steps to reproduce.

1. Change Format dropdown to shortDate.
2. Select date as in year 1921 or 1962 etc.
3. The selected date year would be 2021 or 2062.

Does anyone has any idea about this. Is this a bug in plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about how ui-bootstrap developers have designed  the shortformat.
As you see, there is only 2 digit for the year. I think the two digit are for the actual century. You should open an issue on github and see what they reply.

Comment: I think the plugin knows the year, just before the selection you can see the month and correct year on top of the date picker.

Comment: That's what i did, and it didn''t work. Check by yourself :)